Rudin RCA 10.25: Prove Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using Maximum Modulus Theorem
10.25 Theorem.
If $n$ is a positive integer and
$$
P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1} z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1 z+a_0,
$$
where $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ are complex numbers, then $P$ has precisely $n$ zeros in the plane.
Proof. Choose $r>1+2\left|a_0\right|+\left|a_1\right|+\cdots+\left|a_{n-1}\right|$. Then
$$
\left|P\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|>|P(0)| \quad(0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi) .
$$
If $P$ had no zeros, then the function $f=1 / P$ would be entire and would satisfy $|f(0)|>\left|f\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|$ for all $\theta$, which contradicts the maximum modulus theorem. Thus $P\left(z_1\right)=0$ for some $z_1$. Consequently, there is a polynomial $Q$, of degree $n-1$, such that $P(z)=\left(z-z_1\right) Q(z)$. The proof is completed by induction on $n$.
My Question.
How can I derive $r>1+2\left|a_0\right|+\left|a_1\right|+\cdots+\left|a_{n-1}\right|$ to make sure that $|P(re^{i\theta})|>|P(0)|$?

I want to be sure that I understand your question. Do you want to prove that $r>1+2\left|a_0\right|+\left|a_1\right|+\cdots+\left|a_{n-1}\right|$ works to have the identity satisfied, or do you want to qualify what the lower bound is?

@mathcounterexamples.net The former. I am interested in "what the lower bound is". How can I get the lower bound?

$$|P(z)| = |z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_1z+a_0|\ge |z^n|-|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}| - \dots - |a_1z|-|a_0|$$
by the (reverse) triangle inequality. Now by properties of the absolute value, if we plug in a complex number with modulus $r$, we obtain
$$|P(re^{i\theta})|\ge r^n - |a_{n-1}|r^{n-1} - \dots - |a_1|r - |a_0|. $$
Since $P(0)= a_0$ we want the last expression to be larger than $|a_0|$. The idea now is that for $r$ sufficiently large, the $r^n$-term will dominate, eventually getting bigger than any fixed right hand side. To be precise, if $r>1$ we have
$$|P(re^{i\theta})| \ge r^n \left(1- \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{r} - \dots -\frac{|a_1|}{r^{n-1}} - \frac{|a_0|}{r^n} \right)\ge r^n\left(1- \frac{|a_{n-1}|+ \dots + |a_1| +|a_0|}{r}\right) $$
having used that $\frac{1}{r^k} <\frac{1}{r}$ for $k>1$. Now if $r> |a_{n-1}| + \dots + |a_1|+|a_0|$, the expression in the brackets is positive and we might further estimate
$$|P(re^{i\theta})| \ge r \left(1- \frac{|a_{n-1}|+ \dots + |a_1| +|a_0|}{r}\right) = r- |a_{n-1}|- \dots - |a_1|-|a_0|.$$
The last expression clearly is strictly larger than $|a_0|$ if we choose $r \ge 1+ 2|a_0| + |a_1| + \dots + |a_{n-1}|$ - Note that choosing $r$ in this way also matches the two constraints that we put on $r$ during the derivation ($r>1$ and $r> |a_0| + |a_1|+ \dots +|a_{n-1}|$).
